# Determine if intent filter is used in the app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am trying to clean up the manifest of an app that's been in more or less constant development during the past 4 years. I have written the app myself - and have been the only developer making changes to it - so I have a decent understanding of what's going on in the code. I just haven't been diligent enough to remove things from manifest when they were no longer needed.

Going through the manifest, I can see intent filters being declared, however I vaguely remember that I removed the code that needed that intent filter - as the requirements have changed.

The app is quite large - dozens of activities, hundreds of fragments; the manifest itself is several hundred lines long.

Is there is an easy way to search through the source code to determine if an intent filter declared in the manifest is actually used anywhere?

Comment: filters are put in components that receive the intent .ie activity, broadcast receiver etc, so you can just check the component class registered in the manifest

Comment: @Laser that I know, but I have close to 100 components (activities, services, broadcast receivers) - I was hoping for a non manual solution.

Comment: I think you can use Android's studio's  find usages feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Manifest file and right click on the on the action/category string and select "Find Usages" from the option it will tell you wether its been used or not.

Comment: Yes, find usages is the way to, although in this case it was a bit cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Edit > Find > Find in path` for Android Studio, or [follow this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html) for Eclipse